# Is it awkward to use the word "aubergine" instead of "eggplant"?

Tags: word-choice, british-english, australian-english, north-american-english

According to [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eggplant,%20aubergine&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3) eggplant is far more common (although in [British English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eggplant,aubergine&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3) aubergine seems to have a small advantage over eggplant).

So, not being a native speaker of English I wonder whether using the word "aubergine" would be considered smug or weird by native speakers.

The thing is that I find the word "aubergine" a bit more natural because it's basically the same as in German (*Aubergine*) -- which happens to be my native language.

Comment: Here in the US, people will not understand you if you say *aubergine*.  Not smug or weird, just unintelligible.

Comment: I think many North American speakers would not be familiar with the word aubergine.

Comment: I have a Swiss friend who now lives here in the US. When she first used the word _aubergine_, she was fondling an eggplant. That helped me make the connection rather strongly.

Comment: Equally very few Brits would understand "eggplant"

Comment: FYI Use **brinjal** in India.

Comment: in australia eggplant is more common but people will still understand aubergine.

Comment: This also touches on the "marketing appeal" issue - "squid" (yuk!)vs. "calamari" (num!).

Comment: I first heard "aubergine" a few years ago from a British speaker and had no idea what she meant and was too embarrassed to ask.  I later made the connection when reading a cookbook.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*Aubergine* is the British word (originally, I think, from French, but there's no percentage in guessing exactly how), and many British cooks literally would not know what *eggplant* is.  In North America, as others have said, it's the other way about.

Interestingly, there is another vegetable with the same identity problem; what the British call *courgettes* and the Americans *zucchini*.

Comment: Exactly so. Aubergine is, it appears, a diminutive of ‘auberge’ , in turn a variant of ‘alberge’ and that is, a little mystifyingly, a kind of peach. First appeared in print in Englsh in 1796.

Comment: What's really interesting is that in German, the former is almost exclusively called _Aubergine_ while the latter is exclusively known as _Zucchini_.

Comment: Americans also will have no idea what a *vegetable marrow* might be.

Comment: @Peter Shor: That sounds really weird! Do you still call them "courgettes" if you've let them grow really big? I expect by now most growers use different varieties anyway, but when I was a child helping out on our family allotment, we harvested some of the small marrows early to give the others more chance to grow bigger. And we called those small ones "courgettes" - a real delicacy at the time, as I recall.

Comment: @We don't use either *courgettes* or *vegetable marrows*. At least in the areas I've lived in, vegetable marrows are just one of a variety of different kinds of *summer squash,* and are called that independent of size (but at least some of us know that the small ones are better, though).

Comment: The situation in Australia at least in my lifetime post WWII is that we use *eggplant* and *zucchini*. I always know *aubergine* but never remember what *courgette* means. Both *aubergine* and *courgette* sound French to me and always strike me as odd coming from British people given the lack of love between the two countries. If I heard Australians use either it would sound affected. It could well be that we used these words in Australia before the huge cultural influence of America in the wake of WWII.

Comment: There's also what's called _lady fingers_ in the Orient and _okra_ in the USA. _Aubergine_ and _courgette_ are French, so the British use them; _eggplant_ and _zucchini_ come from English and Italian, respectively (_okra_ is a borrowing from Africa). It's just settlement patterns and dialect divergence, I'm afraid. The usual story.

Comment: Yes, "aubergine" is from French, the color name also. From Catalan albergina, and Arabic  al-badinjan, from Persan badin-gan, and finally from Sanskrit vatigagama. So from "vatigagama" to "aubergine"! (source: etymonline)

Answer (score 6):

In the United States, the word *aubergine* refers almost exclusively to the color  (and almost never to the plant), while in British English, *aubergine* refers to both the plant and the color.

It's worth noting that *aubergine* is the French word for *eggplant*. As is the case with many French loanwords, using *aubergine* over *eggplant* will likely convey a more poetic tone, although you may send some American readers running for a dictionary.

Comment: I agree with this in relation to American usage--I encounter "aubergine" somewhat regularly, but almost exclusively in relation to clothing or home furnishings (where it is, indeed, a slightly high-flown way of saying "purple"). Obviously, *some* Americans know that the word relates to the fruit-vegetable, to make the connection with the color. The OP would be understood by those folks, but it would still be surprising. See image here for Amazon's auto-complete suggestions on "aubergine": http://screencast.com/t/rNgCqqEJdT

Comment: Funnily, aubergine is not at all poetic in French, quite the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

In US English (AmE), there is no such word as 'aubergine', one would only ever refer to the vegetable in question as *eggplant*.

If you were to use the 'other' word, it would not be recognized as anything and so has not connotation of being smug or high class (as a recognizable French word might give, like 'frisson' or 'panache').

I gather though that *aubergine* is perfectly natural in British English, but I can't speak of any nuance related to formality, smugness, or weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not smug or weird. What is important is how to use the words *eggplant* and *aubergine*. This page explains it: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/aubergine?q=aubergine

As with so much of English, how you use it depends on who your audience is. If you are talking to Americans, use the word *eggplant*. If you are talking to British people, use the word *aubergine*.

> The thing is that I find the word "aubergine" a bit more natural
>   because it's basically the same as in German (Aubergine) -- which
>   happens to be my native language.

That's interesting. I didn't know that. Just another example of those things that German and British English have in common.