# Did 'courgettes' ever have an English name?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Americans call them 'zucchini', which I assume is the Italian name, whilst we in Britain use the French name - courgettes.

But I am wondering if the vegetable ever had an English name. The earliest quotation in the OED is from 1931.

Did the Victorians not eat them? I have to admit that they were never part of our diet until the late 1960s.  But they grow perfectly well in the English climate, provided you don't plant them out till after the frosts have finished.

Comment: Hmm... baby marrows?

Comment: What @Mari-Lou said. As a child I sometimes ate baby marrows from our allotment in the early 60s. Not often, because we usually expected to maximise the crop of full-grown marrows later in the year. But in at least a couple of years my father decided there were likely to be too many, so we'd harvest a few very early on. See also the related earlier question [“courgettes” vs. “zucchini” under a historical perspective](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109992/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA In Italian do you have a different word for 'marrow', or does zucchini cover both large and small?

Comment: Not sure if marrows and zucchini/courgettes are the same vegetable, definitely related, but I don't think I've ever seen anyone growing their crop until they are massively overgrown. Zucca (singular) Zucche (pl) are pumpkins in Italian (sorry)

Comment: Could be that zucchini (little zucche) mean the same as baby pumpkins/marrows. But Zucche are normally yellow to orange coloured, either tubular shaped or your normal halloween type pumpkins.

Comment: @Mari-LouA So you don't have marrows?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: According to Wikipedia [they are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courgette) the same. The French *courgette* just means small marrow, *courge* being the French for marrow.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why don't you put that in an answer, so I can give you a tick.

Comment: http://www.greenme.it/abitare/orto-e-giardino/2256-i-10-ortaggi-piu-semplici-da-coltivare-nel-giardino-di-casa there is an image of some large zucchini, would you call them marrows? Zucca and zucchini are completely different vegetables, apparently according to the website, zucchini were introduced in Italy in the 1800s. I don't know if courgettes in the UK were ever called "baby marrows", it was a guess. I had an uncle who grew marrows in his greenhouse.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes they look more or less like marrows. The interesting thing seems to be that the British were later than the French, and the Italians in exploiting the small variety.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That’s really interesting, considering that in Spanish, pumpkins are *calabaza, calabazas* and zucchini are *calabacín, calabacines*. Same sort of diminutive pairing from the starting point, and also the same gender switch.

Comment: @tchrist Interesting that the three romance languages, French, Italian and Spanish should have such widely differing words for these vegetables. I wonder what the Romans called them, if they had them.

Comment: @WS2 Now that ***is*** an excellent question — and an unexpected mystery: [“La palabra calabaza viene de una lengua que se hablaba en la península española antes de la incursión, dominio y extensión del latín por parte del Imperio Romano. ... ”](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?calabaza) The article goes on to probe possible origins, including Greek *κολόκυνθα*, and notes that Seneca himself used the Greek form in a title of his work regarding Claudius, calling it *Apocolokyntosis* (playing on *apotheosis*) conversion into a pumpkin: that is, a fool, a meaning the word retains unto this day.

Comment: The Romans called it *cucurbita*, which just meant *gourd* in Latin, but which gave rise to the name of the genus, *Cucurbita*, and indeed not only to the entire family,  *Cucurbitaceae*, but even the order as well, the *Cucurbitales*.

Comment: To an AmE speaker (me), I have _never_ heard the term 'marrow' before for any kind of squash, zucchini, pumpkin, gourd, small or large or in between.

Comment: @Mitch 'Marrow' is the traditional English name of what is in effect a large courgette.

Comment: @tchrist: the Romans did not have them; zucchini [originated](http://homecooking.about.com/od/foodhistory/a/zucchinihistory.htm) in the Americas, which is undoubtedly why they have so many different names in the Romance languages. The Latin word *cucurbita* must have been used for some other kind of gourd (there are gourds which are native to the Old World, although I can't seem to find any websites that say which species the Romans grew).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Courgettes were first introduced in the UK in the early 1930s and soon several cookery writers began including this versatile vegetable in their recipes. Marcel Boulestin in 1931, translated the French term, courgette, as [baby marrows](http://books.google.it/books?id=Nr2Dna7hx1EC&pg=PA227&dq=baby%20marrows&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LYIOU4PFCOqGywOp1ICABw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=baby%20marrows&f=false), in spite of that the French word stuck and

> The Oxford English Dictionary in its A-G supplement, gives the first
>   use of *courgettes* to E.Lucas in the same year, in 
>   *Vegetable Cookery*

Elizabeth David in 1960, wrote her master book, *French Provincial Cooking*, and said:

> "enterprising growers are supplying us with ***little courgettes*** as an
>   alternative to gigantic vegetable marrows".

Meanwhile in the US, the book *[A Fruit and Vegetable Buying Guide for Consumers](http://books.google.it/books?id=x60oAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA55&dq=green%20italian%20squash&hl=en&sa=X&ei=P4UOU5G_O-XOygP6p4CwDA&ved=0CHAQ6AEwDA#v=onepage&q=Italian%20squash&f=false)*
 by Gerald Rowden Blountthe, published in 1933, tells us that the vegetable was known on some markets as *vegetable marrow*, *Italian vegetable marrow*, or *zucchini*.

*Zucchini* is the Italian term, its singular form, [*zucchina*](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/Z/zucchina.aspx?query=zucchina) or *zucchino* means  "little pumpkin". The term *squash*, gourd, comes from the Indian *skutasquash* also spelled as *asquutasquash*, meaning "green thing eaten green."

---

EDIT: I found an older reference which suggests that the harvesting of immature (baby) marrows was not unheard of in the 19th century. The book entitled *[The New and Improved Practical Gardener, and Modern Horticulturist](http://books.google.it/books?id=e4cEAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=vegetable-marrow&f=false)* by Charles McIntosh, published in London **1839**, refers to marrows as *vegetable-marrows* and claims that it can be eaten at any stage of its growth. Of possible interest, the term *culinary garden* is used throughout the volume, and tomatoes in England were also known as *love-apples*.

[image]

Its Latin name, Cucurbita succada, also explains  the origins of Italian word, *zucca* (pumpkin) and the diminutive term *zucchini*, although both vegetables belong to the same genus, cucurbita, they are quite different from each other, the latter being harvested in the summer months. Wikipedia however, informs us that zucchini belongs instead to the species [Cucurbita pepo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita_pepo)

> The morphological differences within the species C. pepo are so vast
>   that its various subspecies and cultivars have been misidentified as
>   totally separate species. These vast differences are rooted in its
>   widespread geographic distribution. C. pepo is one of the oldest,
>   if not the oldest domesticated species. The oldest known
>   locations are in southern Mexico in Oaxaca 8,000-10,000 years ago and
>   Ocampo, Tamaulipas, Mexico about 7,000 years ago

Comment: As opposed to [*succotash*, which is from a different Indian word (well, Narragansett) *sohquttahhash*, "broken corn kernels"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succotash).

Comment: This is interesting if you can read it, which I presume you can: [“El italiano actualmente emplea preferentemente *zucca*, que algunos ven producto de una reducción y metátesis de la forma *cucuzza*, pero que es más fácil que esté algo influido por el griego *σικύα* de fuerte influjo en la Italia del sur.”](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?calabaza)  The whole article covers all 7 of Spanish, Catalan, Portuguese, Italian, Latin, French, and Greek words for pumpkin/gourd/squash. It’s rather interesting.

Comment: Excellent answer which has explained a curiosity I had held for some time. Thanks.

Comment: @WS2 My pleasure. If your curiosity has been whetted you might be interested in hearing how the term, courgette, became popular in the UK. It seems the cookery writer, [Elizabeth David](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_David) was largely responsible for this, refusing to Anglicize Italian and French produce (my supposition based on Googling).

Comment: @Mari-LouA No high-class cuisine in Britain always employed French terminology. I remember, in the 1950s, staying at a relatively modest hotel in London and finding that the menus were all in French.

Comment: Elizabeth David introduced French, and Mediterranean cuisine to the middle-classes in her book published in 1950. Her recipes included many ingredients which were largely unknown to the humble housewife, and at times, impossible to find in local shops. Certainly *courgette* sounds posher and sexier, (to my ears) and possibly more delicious than the words "baby marrows" or "tiny marrows".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there ever was an English name for them simply because, as you said, it came very lately in England. The Victorians loved the use of French words because it was a sign of good education. So I do think it remained as such in modern English.

Comment: French words are no longer “a sign of good education” in English. English words are.

Comment: Of course, if we use it, the word becomes English by right of conquest.

Comment: @tchrist 'French words are no longer a sign of good education in English'. Upon what authority do you say that?

Comment: I only meant that it used to be a sign of good education and then, as @Oldcat said the word became English "by right of conquest".

Comment: @WS2 Using French words in English says nothing whatsoever about one’s ***English***
education; it says something else. The writer of English who litters his prose avec des mots étrangers is one who ipso facto presents l’esprit not of douce sensibilité attuned to the Zeitgeist of the broader Οἰκουμένη so much as that of the poseur jactant, an élitist snob whose asquerous efforts to elevate himself above vulgus and bourgeoisie alike effects precisely lo contrario of his intended meta. In short, it’s a ***twit marker*** — and quite a reliable one at that, n’est-ce pas? “Render unto France . . .”

Comment: Poseur? C'est qui?

Answer (score 1):

In the US, the term *[summer squash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_squash)* is used for a variety of gourds including *zucchini*.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there never used to be an English word for courgette.
Squash goes back thousands of years, where it was cultivated in Central and South America. After the European’s discovery and subsequent colonisation, the squash found its way to Europe where it became zucchini in Italy and courgette in France. 
Both words translate as small squash (zucca is the Italian word for squash, courge is the French equivalent).
The front man for the courgette was Frenchman Marcel Boulestin who loved England so much that he decided to live in London. He opened up a very expensive French interior design store and wrote about French cooking 
Source: [EVS Translations Word of the Day: Courgette](http://www.evs-translations.com/blog-com/zucchini/)